# A matrix calculus problem with vectorization

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, vectorization

I'm trying to find out the derivative of $vec(AA^T)$ w.r.t to $vec(A)$, where $A$ is a $m$ by $n$ matrix
I use a simple $3$ by $2$ case and find it entry-wisely.
I guess the answer would be $A^T\otimes I_m+[(I_m\otimes a_1),\ (I_m\otimes a_2),\ \ldots,\  (I_m\otimes a_n)]^T$ where $a_i$'s is columns of $A$ (not sure it is correct)
Is there any systematical way to find out such an expression?
My intuitive thought is to express $vec(AA^T)$ as some differentiable function of $vec(A)$ and utilize some simple matrix calculus rule.
Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a vector function, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= {\rm vec}(AA^T) \\
df &= {\rm vec}\Big(I_m\,dA\,A^T+A\,dA^TI_m\Big) \\
   &= (A\otimes I_m)\,da + (I_m\otimes A)K\,da \\
   &= \Big((A\otimes I_m) + (I_m\otimes A)K\Big)\,da \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
   &= (A\otimes I_m) + (I_m\otimes A)K \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with vectorizing a matrix transpose via the Kronecker product.

For a given $(m,n)$ one can readily calculate $K$, e.g. in Julia

```
i = collect(1:m*n)
j = vec(reshape(i,m,n)')
K = sparse(i,j,1)
```

Comment: Is this kind of method (first find the differenial) always in numerator-layout form?(I mean not only in vector-vector differentiation, also something about scalar-matrix differentiation) I'm confused about why my answer and yours are of different dimension.

Comment: @Chc The $a={\rm vec}(A)$ transformation is conventionally defined as stacking the columns of $A$ and therefore $\,{\rm vec}(AA^T) = (A\otimes I_m)\,a + (I_m\otimes A)K\,a.\;$ So I'm not sure how you obtained the term $(A^T\otimes I_m)\,$ that appears in your post. Are you using row-stacking to define ${\rm vec}(A)?\;$

Comment: Our definition of vec( ) is same (stacking the column result in a column vector), the main difference is how we define the derivative of vetors w.r.t vectors, My result is denominator-layouted, and yours is numerator-layouted( they are transpose of each other), see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), I just wonder is this kind of method always produce numerator-layouted result?

Comment: also, I have a question that is transpose of my second term equal to yours second term? It is true for first term obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a common way to do this is to use index notation $A_{ij}$ where $i$ goes over rows and $j$ goes over columns of the matrix. Then

$$F(A)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} A_{jk}$$

Notice that the transpose is just swapping the indices in the second $A_{jk}$. Now we can do the derivative. The trick is to use completely different dummy coefficients for the derivative matrix

$$\frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{mn}} \sum_k A_{ik} A_{jk}$$

Now we will make use of the fact that all coefficients of the matrix are independent. If this is the case, then

$$\frac{\partial A_{ik}}{\partial A_{mn}} = \delta_{im} \delta_{kn}$$

Where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta function, namely, it is equal to 1 if the two coefficients are equal, and 0 otherwise. Thus, using distribution rule for differentiation, we get

$$\frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}} = \sum_k(\delta_{im} \delta_{kn} A_{jk} + A_{ik} \delta_{jm} \delta_{kn}) =
A_{jn} \delta_{im} + A_{in} \delta_{jm}
$$

There are tons of matrix calculus rules, but instead of remembering all of them sometimes it is easier to just derive them from scratch using index notation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't think of this method (directly follow the definition of every entry), but how to simplify the result of every entry to some simple matrix form?